# Change the value of a variable after N milliseconds in Java

Tags: java, time, netbeans-7, thread-sleep

I'm making a game in Java using Netbeans() and I want a Boolean variable takes the value of true when it is taken an item "X", the item "X" represents a character's ability which lasts "N" miliSeconds, what is the best way to do that after "N" miliSeconds the variable returns the value from false?

Comment: Try using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, not sure if it is my place to say, but I have a recommendation and an answer.

I would recommend building a skills/ability library. Use that to track cool downs, casting times etc. It would be more efficient overall.

As for the answer, check to see if the current time minus the time the ability was started is over 1000, then set the variable. Have this be used in a looped system such as a thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); //1 second
    catch (InterruptedException annoyingCheckedException) {}
    x = "foo";
}
```

You can start a new thread which waits a second (or however long you want it to wait) and then changes `x`.

The `try`-`catch` is because when sleeping, Java forces you to catch an `InterruptedException` which will be thrown if the thread is interrupted. In this case, you are never going to interrupt the thread so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a _checked_ exception. Which is why you have to catch it...

Comment: @fge sorry wasn't thinking, I'm tired :P

Comment: Yeah, I had planned to do, but is this the best way to do what I want?

Comment: @Melkhiah66 In this case, yes. In other cases (like when you must execute code that takes a longer time before sleeping) you should check to see if total time passed `> 1000` or however long you want it to take.

Comment: InterruptedException should never be ignored.  If someone wants to interrupt your application, you should respond to it, not ignore it. This will make for the best user experience. At least set the interrupted status on the current thread and return.